# withTrashed not being applied to relation tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am running into this issue where I can't retrieve the soft-deleted data of the relation tables. My approach was to use the `withTrashed` method, but it gave me no luck whatsoever.

This is the line of code:

```
return response()->json($user->orders()->withTrashed()->with('order_details', 'order_details.product', 'address')->get());
```

It ignores what's inside the with clause. How do I fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated, many thanks!

**EDIT**

My Order model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents;

class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes, Notifiable, HasEvents;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'address_id', 'total_price', 'order_status', 'is_delivered'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function address() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Address::class, 'address_id');
    }
    public function order_details() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderDetails::class, 'order_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

My user model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: try this   return response()->json($user->with(['orders'=>function($query){
        $query->withTrashed();
    },'orders.order_details', 'orders.order_details.product', 'address'])->get());

Comment: I will look into it, seems like I also messed up my relationships. Thanks for the help

Comment: not sure whether it will work or not .let me know if any errors

Comment: Right now it tells me the relationships don't exist

Comment: can you post user model and order model

Comment: Sure, just added it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234075/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-sander-plomp).

Comment: .given sollution need to modify ,i had mistake as mentioned by tim

Comment: I was able to make the same happen by just simply using the same line of code as I previously provided in the thread, but instead I added the withTrashed to my model relations. So: return response()->json($user->orders()->with('order_details', 'order_details.product', 'address')->withTrashed()->get()); and then just add to for example: public function order_details() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderDetails::class, 'order_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
    } .... that also did the trick!

Comment: okay.cool.......